# How to split array into two array in VBA

Tags: vba

```
Sub test()
Dim strInput as String
Dim ar2()
Dim ar3()
strInput = "10,20,30,40,50,60,70"
ar1 = Split(strInput, ",")
End Sub
```

How i can Split ar1 array (10,20,30,40,50,60,70) into two array , ar2 = (10,20,30,40,50) and ar3 = (60,70).

Comment: Is there any criteria for the split?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim strInput As String
  Dim IC As Long
  IC = 5 ' Items Count in first array ar1
  Dim ar2()
  Dim ar3()
  strInput = "10,20,30,40,50,60,70"
  ar1 = Split(strInput, ",")

  ReDim ar2(IC - 1)
  ReDim ar3(UBound(ar1) - IC)

  For i = 0 To IC - 1
   ar2(i) = ar1(i)
  Next

  For i = 0 To UBound(ar1) - IC
   ar3(i) = ar1(i + IC - 1)
  Next

'Test:
  Debug.Print "ar2:"
  For i = LBound(ar2) To UBound(ar2)
   Debug.Print ar2(i)
  Next

  Debug.Print "======" & Chr(13) & "ar3:"

  For i = LBound(ar3) To UBound(ar3)
   Debug.Print ar3(i)
  Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by a division point (like say 55 in this case), you can do so like the following (I'm assuming everything below is an integer. You can do the same with floats or doubles, but strings will be a little more difficult if you don't convert them to integers first). To convert a string that really is an integer to an integer, just do `CInt("10")`.

The way I set this up, you have to pass in 2 empty arrays A1 and A2, and this will fill them out:

```
Sub Split(A() As Integer, A1() As Integer, _
    A2() As Integer, Mid As Integer)

    ' Grab the length of array A.
    Dim Alen As Integer
    Alen = UBound(A)

    Dim I As Integer
    Dim SplitIdx As Integer
    SplitIdx = Alen
    ' Loop through A to find out where to split it.
    For I = 1 To Alen
        If A(I) > Mid Then
            SplitIdx = I - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next I

    ' Make sure we aren't doing anything ridiculous.
    If SplitIdx = 0 Or SplitIdx = Alen Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Now we can basically do the same thing that Fadi did.
    ReDim A1(SplitIdx)
    ReDim A2(Alen - SplitIdx)

    ' Now we can just fill it out!
    For I = 1 To Alen
        If I <= SplitIdx Then
            A1(I) = A(I)
        Else
            A2(I - SplitIdx) = A(I)
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

So for example, to use this, you can do something like the following:

```
' Recreate the array as an integer
Dim ar1int() As Integer
For I = 1 To 7
  ar1int = I * 10
Next I

Dim ar2() As Integer
Dim ar3() As Integer
Call Split(ar1int, ar2, ar3, 55)
```